# How to make cells of a row non clickable in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid which have ony two rows. i want the cells of the second row clickable but not for the first row. first row should be read only. i mean first row consists of cells of clickable type and second row consists of cells of non cickable type.
i have tried a lot. i am not getting it done.

Comment: First hit on gooogle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766408/wpf-how-to-disable-cell-edit-in-datagrid ...

Comment: that link is only for changing an entire grid or column. he wants it for just the first row. Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833081/1074345

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i am still not able to find the solution. my scenario is i want to make a timesheet ui which will have a grid which have 5 columns(weekdays) and two rows. one row for dates which i want read only(normal text not clickable) and other row for time. for Time row,each cell consists of linkable time(hours).Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try putting an if statement to check if it is the first row, if it is then return in your event handler.

```
if (dg.CurrentRow == null||dg.CurrentRow == dg.Rows[0])
{ return;}
```